# Sending a POST request with Angularjs and get parameters in a Flask backend

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I have this code in AngularJS:

```
myApp.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.formData = {};

  $scope.doLogin = function(url, pass){
    $http({
      url: url,
      method: "POST",
      data: $.param($scope.formData)
    }).success(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    });
  }
});
```

And in the beckend (Flask), I have this:

```
def user_authenticate():
    login = request.args.get('login')
    password = request.args.get('password')
    print login, password
```

The problem is that request.args come empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After have a lot of problems with this, I solve using another Stackoverflow answer. So, I got this code:

**ANGULARJS**

```
$scope.doLogin = function(url, pass){
    $http({
      url: url,
      method: "POST",
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).success(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    });
 }
```

**FLASK**

```
def view_of_test():
    post = request.get_json()
    param = post.get('param_name')
```

**OLD VERSION**

I just figured that I need to change my code to this:

AngularJS:

```
myApp.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.formData = {};

  $scope.doLogin = function(url, pass){
    $http({
      url: url,
      method: "POST",
      data: $.param($scope.formData),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).success(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    });
  }
});
```

Just include the 'Content-Type' header.

Flask:

```
def user_authenticate():
    login = request.form.get('login')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    print login, password
```

Instead of use request.args, use request.form.

Comment: That's because `request.args` contains url parameters (so everything after the `?`) only, `request.form` contains POST fields.